# Opinion: JMS vs ebXML

Tags: java, jms, ebxml

This is not so much a question as it is a request for an opinion on these two technologies. A little background on this: I suggested the use of JMS on an enterprise project and the client came back talking about ebXML. I can honestly say I had no idea what this was, never read about it on the wire, and never hear anyone talking about it anywhere. So as a community, what do you guys think about one over the other?

JMS
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service

ebXML
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebxml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the privilege of having worked on both the JMS RI at Sun and the ebXML at OASIS. I agree with previous statement that it is apples and oranges comparison....

- JMS is a Java API. ebXML is a set of XML specifications and protocols. This is quite different
- JMS defines an API for pub/sub messaging requiring a Java Message Service. ebXML is a set of specifications that do many things ranging from technical agreements on how to interact using a common set of capabilities (ebXML CPPA), registry and repository (ebXMl RegRep, and a messaging service (ebXML Messaging). The last spec may be the one that you were comparing JMS with.
- [1] has a useful comparison of JMS and ebXML Messaging....

"Although the Java Messaging Service (JMS) offers a standard programming interface to message queuing products, the message formats and wire protocols used by these products are proprietary, requiring sender and recipient to use implementations from the same vendor or to use JMS-to-JMS bridges. One promise of the ebXML Messaging Service is to provide some of the benefits of message queuing products, while offering users a choice of ebMS implementations, provided by different vendors, including open source implementations."

[1] The ebXML Messaging Service, By Pim van der Eijk, March 18, 2003
http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1175

Answer (score 0):

Seems like apples and oranges to me, but from the Wikipedia article it wasn't entirely clear what implementations had to provide.

I'd have to be convinced to *not* use an EE standard like JMS if it suits the messaging needs you actually have.